# Key, Value, Hash and Hash function for HashTable

Tags: hash, hashset

I'm having trouble understanding what the Hash Function does and doesn't do, as well as what exactly a Bucket is.

From my understanding:

A HashTable is a data structure that maps keys to values using a Hash Function.

A HashFunction is meant to map data from an array of arbitrary/unknown size to a data array of fixed size.

There can be duplicate Values in the original data array, but this is irrelevant.

Each Value will have a unique Key. Thus, each Key has exactly 1 Value.

The HashFunction will generate a HashCode for each (Value, Key) pair. However, Collisions can occur in which multiple (Value, Key) pairs map to the same HashCode.

This can be remedied by using either Chaining/Open Addressing methods.

The HashCode is the index value indicating the position of a particular entry from the original data array within the Bucket array.

The Bucket array is the fixed data array constructed that will contain the entries from the original array.

My questions:

How are the Keys generated for each value? Is the HashFunction meant to generate both Key and HashCode values for each entry? Does each Bucket thus contain only one entry (assuming a Chaining implementation to remedy Collision)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How are the Keys generated for each value?

Key is not generated, it is provided by you and serves as an input to the hash function which in turn converts that key into index of hash table. Simply speaking:

```
H(key)=index
```

so the value you are looking for is:

```
hash_table[index] = value
```

> Is the HashFunction meant to generate HashCode values for each entry?

It all depends on the implementation of hash function and hash table. Some hash functions might generate a hashcode out of provided key and then for example take its `modulo(size)` where `size` is the size of hash table, in order to get the index. Others might convert the key directly into index. In either case the ultimate goal of hash function is to find the location of searched data within hash table in constant time.

> Does each Bucket thus contain only one entry (assuming a Chaining implementation to remedy Collision)?

Ideally each key should be mapped to a unique index but mostly that's not the case since the number of buckets (i.e. indices) is far smaller than the number of keys so the average length of a chain per bucket (i.e. number of collisions per bucket) is `no.of keys/no.of indices`

Comment: So then is it more appropriate to say: HashCode should be a method that generates an integer value (the hashcode) for a particular (value, key) pair and ideally this would be unique; HashFunction should be a method that maps each (value, key) pair to a location in the Bucket array based off of the hashcode?

Comment: @K.Doe for a particular "key". not (value, key)

Comment: @K.Doe forget about value. Value is just something that you want to store. Hashing does not deal with it

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much!